# Displaying duplicate string on index only once in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame({
'Foo': ['John','John','John','Steve','Steve','Ted'],
'Score': [4.1,6,5,7,6,0],
'Picotee':[0,1,0,1,0,0]
})

df = df.set_index('Foo', append=True)

print(df)
```

That prints to:

```
>>> 
         Picotee  Score
 Foo                  
John         0    4.1
John         1    6.0
John         0    5.0
Steve        1    7.0
Steve        0    6.0
Ted          0    0.0
```

Is it possible to have the output only display the duplicate entries once in the index column 'Foo' so it looks like

```
>>> 
         Picotee  Score
 Foo                  
John         0    4.1
             1    6.0
             0    5.0
Steve        1    7.0
             0    6.0
Ted          0    0.0
```

Comment: What is the reason you need to do this `df.set_index('Foo', append=True)`?

Comment: @JoeR No reason just left over pseudocode from something else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per your comment, you wont need this line:`df = df.set_index('Foo', append=True)` so you can just take that out and use simple `pivot_table`

```
pd.pivot_table(df, index=['Foo', 'Score'])
```

Output:

```
                Picotee
Foo     Score   
John    4.1     0
        5.0     0
        6.0     1
Steve   6.0     0
        7.0     1
Ted     0.0     0
```